# Possible bug in UI-Router v 0.2.11 : Template injected in ui-view multiple times for each state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

During working on an angularJS app using Ui-Router I noticed that the the $scope method in the controller are called multiple times when a view is loaded. After some investigation it came down to the Ui-Router itself and it seemed like for every state the template is injected in ui-view multiple times.

To confirm that I created the simplest ui-router based navigation app with 2 templates and one controller and was able to reproduce the same problem.

I created a Plunk based on this test that [you can see and try it here](http://plnkr.co/IRVyja)

Here is the source of index.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div><a ui-sref="page1">Page 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a ui-sref="page2">Page 2</a></div>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <script src="angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
    ])

        .config(function ($stateProvider) {

            $stateProvider

              .state('page1', {
                  url: '/1',
                  templateUrl: 'page1.html',
                  controller: 'mainCtrl'
              })

                .state('page2', {
                    url: '/2',
                    templateUrl: 'page2.html',
                    controller: 'mainCtrl'
                })
        }
    )

    .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.log = log;

        function log(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            return true;
        }

    });
})();
```

page1.html

```
<h1>Page 1</h1>
<div ng-if="log('page 1')"></div>
```

page2.html

```
<h1>Page 2</h1>
<div ng-if="log('page 2')"></div>
```

When running this sample open your browser's console and then click on Page1 and Page 2. You will see each state change logs a message 2 or 3 times.

I've searched on the web but seems like no one else has reported this issue so it might be some wrong doing on my end. I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: It's working as designed.  Every time you go to a "page" in AngularJs a new controller is created.  That is how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you experience is not related to the `UI-Router`. Let me use few cites from this post *(and you can find many more others about `$apply()` and `$digest()`)*:

#### [Understanding Angular’s $apply() and $digest()](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) by Sandeep Panda

> **$apply and $digest Explored**
>
> ...When you write an expression ({{aModel}}), behind the scenes Angular sets up a watcher on the scope model...

And this is exactly what happened on your view here:

```
<div ng-if="log('page 1')"></div>
```

The **ng-if** directive is now part of the digest cycles and is checked if its value did not change. When it happens? How often?:

> **How Many Times Does the $digest Loop Run?**
>
> ...The answer is that the $digest loop doesn’t run just once. At the end of the current loop, it starts all over again to check if any of the models have changed. This is basically dirty checking, and is done to account for any model changes that might have been done by listener functions. **So, the $digest cycle keeps looping until there are no more model changes, or it hits the max loop count of 10**...

And that's it. You've triggered some action *(click on the link, with directive `ui-sref`)*. The angular environment has started to do its job. No error... No issue in `UI-Router`

You've just not selected the right place to expect to be evaluated only once